# VS2010 debugger takes an unreasonable amount of time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Anyone else dealt with VS2010 debug in C++ and have it just sit there for 30+ second each time you step?  This is happening to me and the call stack window just has this grey thing that says "Busy..." in it during this freeze.  The whole interface just locks down...each and every step I make and right now I'm trying to step through this massive policy based design in boost to figure out WTF I got a, "no RTTI data," error when I know the compiler is using RTTI.

Anyway, its frustrating the holy hell out of me so if anyone has any idea how to speed this thing up to at least a snail's pace that would be great.

Comment: I have had no such difficulties with large, unmanaged C++ projects.

Comment: It looks like the bugs have defeated the debugger. Poison resistance?

Comment: Close a reasonable question??  I guess some people are just 100% sphincter muscle.

Comment: Consider creating a bug ticket at Connect (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback). Also, a minidump during one of those 30s hangs (better yet, several ones to ensure the real problem is captured) would also be extremely helpful for investigating this kind of thing.

Comment: Is the debugger kicking in during a stack overflow? (Or near one.) I've had the debugger perform terribly when stack space is gone or low.

Comment: It could be something with stack size.  Boost.Serialize does have quite the stack.  Figured out the problem (sort of) though and have sort of abandoned the idea of figuring out why VS gets dog slow in those cases.  I just try to make sure I never write any bugs :p

Comment: BTW, why do people keep editing questions, like this one, and not actually changing anything??

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen these?

[Visual Studio debugger slows down in in-line code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138917/visual-studio-debugger-slows-down-in-in-line-code)

[Slow debugging issue in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589338/slow-debugging-issue-in-visual-studio)

Comment: No, I didn't.  Unfortunately they don't seem to address my particular problem.  Some suggest it was fixed in 2008 sp1 but I have an even more updated compiler.  Suppose it could be a regression but then I'm screwed.  It is inline code...

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using data breakpoints or conditional breakpoints are you? Both of these slow down running/stepping significantly.

Comment: No.  Thanks for the attempt though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar problems in the past if the debugger is trying to download symbols from a symbol server and either the server connection is slow (or can't be reached) or there's some problem saving them.  So firstly check the symbol settings (Debug -> Options -> Symbols).  Try disabling symbol lookup entirely or if you're using a local symbol server then check the accessibility and directory permissions.

If that doesn't solve it then try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) during the hang as this may show you what's going wrong, eg if something is trying to access a network drive or a file or directory that doesn't exist.  It may give you enough hints to diagnose the problem.